# Using React Bootstrap + Next.JS, How do i go about getting the content of a textbox within a React Component and sending it back to my Index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js, react-bootstrap

I'm a bit stuck here.

I'm trying to get the data from one of my React Components i've made, called ParameterList, which contains a React-Bootstrap Form.Control element, that allows for numerical input.

I want to be able to take that value and send it back to a method in my index.js

I've read a few stackoverflow threads, the docs and a couple youtube videos and it seems like using ReactRefs is the best way to do it, however, i've not been able to find any resources talking about using it when reffing something that is a couple components deep in the react hierarchy, and most of them seem to be using different syntax for their classes than i am. Or maybe it just went right over my head

I think i have a halfway alright understanding of ReactRefs, but i'm very lost on how i implement them into my circumstances.

Here's my ParameterList.js Component file

```
import { Button, Row, Col, Container, Form } from "react-bootstrap"
import styles from "../styles/ParameterList.module.scss"

const ParameterList = ({onRandomList, onNewList, onClear}) => {
    
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.container} id="paramsDiv">
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <Col align="center">
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Label>Generate an entirely new list of instruments</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="Minimum" min="0"/>
                            <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="Maximum" min="0"/>
                            <Button type="button" onClick={onRandomList}>Generate Random List</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                    
                    <Col align="center">
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Label>Add a random group of new instruments</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="Amount of Instruments" min="0"/>
                            <Button type="button" onClick={onNewList}>Generate Random Instrument(s)</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Label>Other Parameters</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Check label="No Duplicates?" id="noDupes"/>
                            <Button type="button" variant="warning" onClick={onClear}>Clear List</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}


export default ParameterList
```

And here is the method in my index.js in which i want to implement it. The parameter list is being drawn in the "return()" of the index.js, just an FYI.

```
const addNewInstruments = () => {
        var insCount = ??????; //Right here is where i want to get the value of that Form.Control
    
        for (i = 0; i < insCount; i++) {
            var newInst = allInstruments[Math.floor(Math.random() * allInstruments.length)]
            newInst.locked = false
            setMyInstruments([...myInstruments, newInst])
        } 
    }
```

I attempted to use ReactRefs to create a reference within my Form.Control like this, which i got from another StackOverflow question, however, im really not sure what to make "this.myInput" into.

```
<Form.Control inputRandomGroupRef={ref => {this.myInput = ref;}} type="number" placeholder="Amount of Instruments" min="0"/>
```

After reading about ReactRefs, it really seems like the way to go, but i really have no idea how to implement it into my current structure, like, having to pull the ref out of this react-bootstrap component that is within my react component that is within my overall index.js. I'm just really not sure the best way to go about this, and i was hoping you guys could help me learn and steer me right.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is change addNewInstruments to accept the variable as parameter `const addNewInstruments = (insCount) => {`

Pass it to the child component `<ParameterList addNew={addNewInstruments} ...`

Then call it from the component directly or in a local function that has access to the input value.

```
const ParameterList = ({onRandomList, onNewList, onClear, addNew}) => {
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.container} id="paramsDiv">
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    ...
                    <Col align="center">
                        <Form>
                            <Form.Label>Numbers</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="number" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" value={numberInState} onChange={(e) => setNumberInState(e.target.value)}/>
                            <Button type="button" onClick={() => addNew(numberInState)}>Generate Random Instrument(s)</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Col>
```

Comment: This is a great reply, and it makes a lot of sense to me in my head, but when i tried to apply the code, it gave me a ReferenceError, telling me that "numberInState" is not defined, referring to it's implementation within the Form.Control "value={numberInState}". Any idea why that might be?

Comment: `const ParameterList = ({onRandomList, onNewList, onClear, addNew}) => {
  const [numberInState, setNumberInState] = useState(0);
...`

Comment: Ah! I see now! I should have noticed that! Thank you for the clarification and all the help! Of course i was overthinking this lol.

Answer (score 1):

You should use useState for form values.

```
const Form = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  return <input type='text' value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
}
```

The pattern here applies pretty much no matter what framework or library you're using.

What's more is that if a parent in the tree needs this value, then instead use that useState in the parent and pass down the ""value" and "setValue" callback from the parent.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  return <ChildComponent value={value} setValue={setValue}/>
}

const ChildComponent = ({value, setvalue}) => {
  return <input type='text' value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}/>
}
```